# How do I get the full name of an S3 bucket which contains a given string using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Terraform deploys an S3 bucket using a name prefix.

How do I get the full name of an S3 bucket by providing name prefix to the AWS CLI command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aws s3api list-buckets --query 'Buckets[*].[Name]' --output text | grep "admin-passwords"
```

Using the above AWS CLI command and providing the name prefix/string/identifier to the grep command we can achieve the desired output.

Output:

```
admin-passwords202104262231251212001
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of AWS command to list all the buckets and grep your string/identifier from the output of that command. Since all the buckets names are unique, it should work easily. For example -

```
aws s3 ls | grep "my-bucket-identifier"
```